# How can we create an instance in C++ by a string type name?

Tags: c++, reflection

Suppose we only have a string

```
string typename = "int"
```

How can we get an instance by this typename.

Comment: You can use a factory returning a union.

Comment: @Luchian: Only for POD types.

Comment: What is your intention? When thinking this way, I usually get stuck on 'C++ doesn't work this way' and realign my thinking process.  If you would get an instance of 'int', it would be as a `void*`.  No garbage collection would mean tracking these objects very carefully.  And so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a derived class instance from a string of its name. (i.e, reflection)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231205/generating-a-derived-class-instance-from-a-string-of-its-name-i-e-reflection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you **cannot** have a type just from a `string` (or character array). Type **must be declared at compile time**.

[P.S. `typename` is a keyword in C++, so it cannot be used as variable.]

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly supported in C++. You could use the `Abstract Factory Pattern` (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for it) and map the names of the class to the factory to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly in C++.

The usual way it's done is registering all possible types in some factory that will create the data on the heap.